# Dealing with instances of MovieClips in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, instance

I have been having trouble in getting data of `MovieClips` of the same names, yet stored inside different `MovieClips` all together.

**What I Have:**

1. An Object with instance `workScreen` of class `FashionFrenzy` which contains all the rest of the `MovieClips` that I mention next.

*Added using AS3 using `addChild` method in constructor code and function codes of `workScreen`:*

2. 12 Objects of class Shop which have a member `displayArt` of `MovieClip` type. These `MovieClips` are stored using an `array shopMCs` when then objects are created within a loop.

*`shopMCs` array:*

```
shopMCs = new Array(Snacks_mc,Jewellery_mc,Music_mc,Tops_mc,Bottoms_mc,Movies_mc,Purses_mc,Shoes_mc,Groceries_mc,Electronics_mc,Furniture_mc,Watches_mc,Counter_mc);
```

All these `MovieClips` are present physically over `workScreen.` These link perfectly and do all the functions as required.

3. *This is where my problem comes.* I made a new Object of instance `realShop` of Class `RealShop`. This real shop again contains all the MCs in the shopMC array with **exactly same** instance name so that I have better control.

Whenever the `gameTimer` ; object of of `Timer` Class in my game which controls all the time related things in my game; reaches a specified number, the function  `openDayEndScreen` launches.

openDayEndScreen function:

```
public

function openDayEndScreen(event: DayEndEvent) {

  // I am perfectly sure this event is being dispatched and this function is running.
  Time_mc.gameTimer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, GenerateBuyers);
  Time_mc.gameTimer.reset();


  for each(var buyer_mc: Buyer in buyers) {
    removeChild(buyer_mc);


  }

  buyers.splice(0, buyers.length); // till here I have no troubles.

  realShop.x = 0;
  realShop.y = 0;
  addChild(realShop); // I have placed realShop.
  shopMCs = new Array(Snacks_mc, Jewellery_mc, Music_mc, Tops_mc, Bottoms_mc, Movies_mc, Purses_mc, Shoes_mc, Groceries_mc, Electronics_mc, Furniture_mc, Watches_mc, Counter_mc); // this is the array

  //shops is the array containing all the Shop objects. 
  for (var bigLooper: int = 0; bigLooper < shops.length; bigLooper++) {
    //bigLooper goes to each shop one by one.
    for (var looper: int = 0; looper < shopMCs.length; looper++) {
      //looper checks for the place in shopMc where the MovieClip instance is same as the displayArt.
      if (shopMCs[looper] == shops[bigLooper].displayArt) {
        break;
        //looper is saved.
      }
    }

    if (shops[bigLooper].shopOpen) {
      upgrade_btn = new UpgradeButton; //NOT throwing errors.
      trace(realShop.shopMCs[looper]); // I am trying to access the SAME MOVIECLIP instance in the     realShop; all these are throwing errors.
      upgrade_btn.x = realShop.shopMCs[looper].x; //all these are throwing errors.
      upgrade_btn.y = realShop.shopMCs[looper].y; //all these are throwing errors.
      addChild(upgrade_btn); //NOT throwing errors.

    } else { //do nothing for a while

    }
  }



}
```

What this function is trying to do is place an Object of class `UpgradeButton` over respective `MCs` in the `realShop` , taking reference from the `Shop` class item's `displayArt`'s postion; `looper`. I have marked down details in comments.

So, the compiler throws error  when `realShop.shopMCs[looper]` is accessed.

**Error:**

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is undefined and has no properties.    at
>   FashionFrenzy/openDayEndScreen()  at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()     at
>   flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()     at
>   FashionFrenzy/checkDayTimerEnd()  at
>   flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()   at flash.utils::Timer/tick()

How do I acchieve what I want without compiler throwing errors?

Comment: Which line of code is the error coming from?

Comment: Whenever I acess realShop.shopMCs[looper]  , it's showing errors.

Comment: Well how is your `realShop` getting `shopMCs`?

Comment: @AndreyPopov    my realShop also has the MCs of shopMCs instances. I want to control the same name instance of outside realShop and inside realShop.

Comment: You either have to set this property, get it as a child (if it's inside) or use `public dynamic class` in order for this to work. If you want to get a child that's added inside a container, you should use `getChildAt` or `getChildByName`.. If it's not child, but a property, then I don't see where you set it.

Comment: @AndreyPopov  I tried searching about getChildByName and getChildAt properties. I think I understood "ByName" but not "At". When I use: trace(realShop.getChildByName(shopMCs[looper]));  , it showed Null. but when I used  trace(realShop.getChildByName(shopMCs[looper])); ,  it traced out [Object Shape]. Atleast I'm not getting error this time but either way, the x and y properties are not being retrived and the update button still remains in (0,0) when it shouldnt. I'm still sure the instance name is the same. Where do you think I'm going wrong?

Comment: @AndreyPopov when I manually trace out trace(realShop.Groceries_mc); , it traces out [object Groceries_16] . This confirms that it exisits.

Comment: Seems odd to be using a for loop var after you are outside the loop. You are still inside bigLooper, but not looper. upgrade_btn.x = realShop.shopMCs[looper].x;

Comment: @AndrewSellenrick when I traced shopMCs[looper] it works just fine. My ActionScript Book taught me that flash considers variables of loops' scope not only within loop but outside it as well.

Comment: Just wasnt sure what the code was doing. At that point in the code the looper variable will always be (shopMCs.length-1)